# encode jpg and save to server via php

Tags: php, encode, jpeg, processing.js

I am passing a byte array of pixel values from Processing.js to javascript where its base 64 encoded and passed via POST to a php page.  I need the php page to encode it as a jpg and save the image to my server. What is the best way to accomplish this?  Preferably all through PHP if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you'd only need [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/base64_decode) [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) and [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/imagejpeg), unless there is some obstacle you didn't mention.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be one way (I'm just telling you some algorithm)-

step 1- decode the array of pixel values.

step 2 - create a image object.

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(height, width);
```

step 3 - for loop for looping from 0 to height (x-direction)

step 4 - for loop for looping from 0 to width 9 (y-direction)

step 5 - use GD's `imagesetpixel($image, $x-coordinate , $y-coordinate, 0xff & PIXEL VALUE YOU GOT);`

write to file or output to response's output stream in HTTP.
step 6 - `imageJPEG($image);`

Comment: This will take some time if the image is large, but I don't see a better way of doing it natively in PHP.